# Return certain row from Scala table with SQL

Tags: sql, python-3.x, scala, apache-spark

I'm very new to Databricks and Spark, so I hope my question is clear. If not, please let me know.

I have a folder in azure with more than 2 million XML-files. The goal is to convert all these files into one CSV-file. I have code that can convert XML to CSV and then add it to a CSV-file in azure. I've tested it with 50.000 files and it worked.

However, when I want to convert all XML-files (+2 million), I get the error that the driver limit is exceeded. I do not want to increase this limit, since it is not very efficient, so I came up with the idea to convert one XML-file at a time and then add it (append) to the CSV-file. So instead of converting all XML-files in one job, I want to convert one XML-file per job.

A colleague was able to develop a code in Scala that creates a table with all +2 million file paths. I can access this table sing SQL:

[image]

(The full paths are not shown due to security reasons).

What I actually need is a code in Python that can loop thru this table and retrieve one path (as string) at a time. The reason I need this in Python is because I have the code to convert to CSV in Python. The conversion only needs the path as string to perform. If I’m able to put this in a loop, each loop a new string is retrieved from the table as string, converted to CSV and then added to one CSV-file.

So my question is: how can I loop thru this table, returning the path (value of the table) as string with each iteration? This iteration should be able to go thru the whole list (+2 million paths).

I hope my question is clear and someone can help.

Best regards,

Ganesh

Comment: It's clear, but it's a bit broad.. what would you like the answer to look like? A few sentences of recommendations what python functions to use to open an xml and retrieve a value at an xpath? Or are you looking for someone to do the work for you? The problem is, if you're looking for the first thing, you know what you want to do so you can google it and have a go yourself. If you're looking for the second thing, zero cost freelance isn't what we're here for..

Comment: First of all, I'm very sorry that I made you think to do the work for me, that was not my intention. For the first thing: I did google it, and found something for a couple of files, but not for +2 million files. Also, I'm used to Pandas where I can iterate over rows whenever I want, but I'm not used to Spark dataframe. I need to have a way to iterate over Spark dataframe rows.